# Why anonymous class can't access private methods and variables?

Tags: java, inheritance, anonymous-class

```java
package demo;

class Child{
    private static int a=50;
    public void fin() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    private void fly() {
        System.out.println("lol");
    }
}

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  
        Child c=new Child() {

            public void f() {
                System.out.println("sorry"+a);
            }
            public void fin() {
                System.out.println("hello");

            }

        };
        c.fin();

}}
```

Above is the code of java my point is why cant private methods and variables be called in anonymous class as I had read somewhere that an anonymous class can access all members of enclosed class.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-anonymous-classes
go checkout which specifies that each member of the anonymous class can access all members of the enclosed class.

Comment: Lol private methods can't be overwritten.... that wouldn't make any sense because they are only visible inside their defined class

Comment: That's how java or any other object oriented language work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a confusion in that code about "inner class" and "anonymous class".

Notice you have 3 classes there:

- `Child`
- `Hello`
- `Hello$1`: An anonymous class declared inside of `Hello` and whose parent is `Child`

The confusion in the code is about the latter:

- `Hello$1` is a subclass of `Child`
- `Hello$1` is an inner class of `Hello`

This means:

- `Hello$1` cannot access private fields from `Child`, as subclasses cannot access private elements of their super classes
- `Hello$1` can access private fields from `Hello`, as anonymous inner classes can access private elements of their enclosing classes

Check it more clearly in this code:

```java
class Child {
    private int a = 50;
}

public class Hello {
    private int b = 60;

    public void f() 
    {  
        Child c = new Child() {
            public void f() {
                // System.out.println("a = " + a); // This won't compile
                System.out.println("b = " + b); // This compiles OK
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thank u very much brother, I completely misundestood it,,

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you're anonymously overriding class is inconsequential to the situation. A class cannot access its parent's `private` members. If you want to access the parent's members you could define them with `protected` or default visibility.

Answer (score 1):

> i had read somewhere that anonymous class can access all members of enclosed class.

I assume you mean of enclosing class and yes. However `Child` is not the enclosing class it's the parent class. The enclosing class in your case would be `Hello.class` and if you add to it `private static int a;` i.e:

```
public class Hello {
    private static int a = 40;
...
```

It will work.